# Set dropdown value from another option with database

Tags: php, ajax

For example I have intake and courses database. In intake I have A and B data.
And in courses I have a PHP with intake A as foreign key, and  Jquery with intake B as foreign key.

So in form, if I select "A" as a intake, later in course option or dropdown there will be "PHP" value.

*Edit

Set dropdown option from another dropdown value using AJAX.

Here is the Ajax function

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function Intake()
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "IntakeDropdown.php",
            //data: { id_option: $(object).val(), operation: 'get_subjects' },
            contentType ="application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                //Clear options corresponding to earlier option of first dropdown
                  //$('#Iname').empty();
                  $('#Iname').html("<option> value='0'>--Select Intake--</option>");
                       //Populate options of the second dropdown
               $.each(data, function(i,item)
               {
                   $('#Iname').html('<option value="'+ data[i].id+'">'+ data[i].name+'</option>');
               });
               //$('#Iname').focus();
            },
                complete: function(){

                }
            });
         }

          function Courses(sid)
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CoursesDropdown.php?sid="+sid,
            //data: { id_option: $(object).val(), operation: 'get_subjects' },
            contentType ="application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                //Clear options corresponding to earlier option of first dropdown
                  //$('#Courses').empty();
                  $('#Courses').html("<option> value='0'>--Select Courses--</option>");
                       //Populate options of the second dropdown
               $.each(data, function(i,item)
               {
                   $('#Courses').html('<option value="'+ data[i].id+'">'+ data[i].name+'</option>');
               });
               //$('#Courses').focus();
            },
                complete: function(){

                }
            });
         }

         $(document).ready(function(){
          Intake();
          $("#Iname").change(function(){
            var intakeid = $("#Iname").val();
            Courses(intakeid);
          });
         });
    </script>

      </head>
```

**IntakeDropdown.php**

```
<?php
            include "connect.php";

            $checkuser = "Select * from Intake";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $checkuser);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($results2)) {
                $data = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results2)) {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'id' => $row['IntakeID'],
                        'name' => $row['IntakeName'],
                    );
                }
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
?>
```

**CoursesDropdown**

```
<?php
            include "connect.php";

            $checkuser = "Select * from courses Where IntakeID ='" . $_GET("sid") . "'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $checkuser);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($results2)) {
                $data = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results2)) {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'id' => $row['CoursesID'],
                        'sid' => $row['IntakeID'],
                        'name' => $row['CoursesName'],
                    );
                }
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: [sample of the form](http://imgur.com/iIUg6WD)

Comment: forger to fetch data from result set

Comment: Question is bit unclear, try to add more information.

Comment: hmm sorry. Ok so after i research the topic it is regarding with **populate a dropdown from another dropdown**. So in here, im trying to implement that things by using AJAX. I already tried, but nothing happen ` `

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` function which fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

```
    <?php  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM courses where CoursesIntake ='$ScheduleIntake'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while($coursesintake=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $coursesintake["CoursesName"]; ?>"> <?php echo $coursesintake["CoursesName"]; ?></option>
   <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Ahh mixing mysql api

Comment: need to be change in explanation too!!